# Посоветуйте базу данных для хранения больших таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql, mongodb

Какая бд лучше справиться  с хранением больших таблиц, +30-50G.
Из вариантов MySQL 8.0 vs PostgreSQL vs MongoDB, какая справиться лучше и какие плюсы и минусы у них?

Comment: Если данные могут спокойно лечь в монгу - я бы взял её и соорудил бы кластер.

Comment: Начинать надо не с объема таблицы, а с того что в ней будет лежать и как с этим будет происходить работа. Например реляционные по своей природе данные _нельзя_ хранить в noSQL БД, такой как mongodb, иначе получите массу проблем. Если же наоборот, данные не реляционны и имеют более свободную структуру - то noSQL решение может быть лучшим выбором

Comment: И если речь про MySQL именно 8 версии, то внимательно посмотрите не предполагается ли хранение иерархических структур вида родитель-ребенок, запросы к таким данным на этой версии лучше не делать

Comment: @Mike _"запросы к таким данным на этой версии лучше не делать"_ а что с ней не так?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov В 8 версии еще нет рекурсивного CTE, а на переменных делать рекурсивные запросы то еще извращение и главное, дико тормозное

Comment: @Mike а, понятно, что имелось ввиду. Но можно же nested set или closure tables использовать

Comment: Данные будут реплицироваться и разных серверов в одну бд.Серверов будет около 200, данные это обычные mysql таблицы но отношение между таблицами сохранятся не будет, главное их хранить.

Comment: Хранить без возможности выборки ? Может тогда просто в файлы бекапить и складывать

Comment: Любая из этих баз данных может спокойно хранить такой объем данных. А вот сможете ли вы потом с ними нормально работать и не ждать пару суток пока отработает простейший `select` с индексом, это уже другой вопрос и лучше о нем заранее подумать.